# Microservice breakpoints not hit in VS 2022

Tags: debugging, dependency-injection, microservices, visual-studio-2022

I am having an issue with breakpoints not being hit in Debug mode for any of the solution's microservices, regardless of whether I run them individually or as multiple startup projects alongside my web app.

I don't get any warnings whatsoever. I run the app **on the browser** which in turn calls the MS, but the MS responds without the breakpoint ever being hit. There is one caveat though, we added **swagger** on one of the MSs and through that, the breakpoints are hit as expected.

I am using VS 2022 (recently upgraded to 17.3), Dependency Injection and .net core 6.
Any ideas?

Comment: I'm afraid the question is impossible to answer; There could be a thousand reasons why your break point isn't hit.

Comment: @Steven - What's the 1st out of the thousand that comes to mind? :D I'm clutching at straws ATM anyway :)

Comment: Hover over the breakpoint and see if there's any warning? This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/troubleshooting-breakpoints?view=vs-2022) is about some warnings and how to fix them. Hope it useful for you.

Comment: @JingmiaoXu-MSFT - thanks for the link, I'll take a look at it. As I've already mentioned, there are no "warnings whatsover".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone struggling with this, I managed to find a solution.

Because my MSs were running on `IIS`, I went through every single MS's `launch` settings and I set the process to `IIS`.
I then re-applied the solution's Multiple Startup Projects, and breakpoints are now hit as expected.